Commutability of matrix and vectors
i was reading a proof of the singular value decomposition of matrices from Friedberg et al. Linear Algebra, in the proofs they want to demonstrate that the matrices $AV = U\Sigma$  and then since $U$ and $V$ are the matrices which $j$-th column is an orthonormal vector in a basis, (derived by applying singular value theorem on the transformation $L_A(x) = Ax$, and $\Sigma$ is defined as $\Sigma_{i,j} = \sigma_i \space\space \forall i : 1\leq i \leq r = rank(A), \space \Sigma_{i,j} = 0 \space \forall i : i\geq r$. And so $Av_j = \sigma_j u_j$ where $v_j$ are columns in $V$ and $u_j$ are columns in $U$, (knowing that $v_j$ and $u_j$ are vectors in the orthonormal bases from the singular value theorem. Then the passage that i don't get is: the columns of $U\Sigma$ are given by $$U(\sigma_je_j) = \sigma_jU(e_j) = \sigma_ju_j$$
why does this commutes?

the $\sigma_j$  are not vectors, they are single numbers, sometimes called scalars

apparently Theorem 6.27, page 406.   Note that $\Sigma_{i,j}  = 0$  when $i \neq j$
